# Referencing a silverlight class library in a WP7 project

Tags: windows-phone-7, dll, silverlight-4.0

I've created a simple testing class library using silverlight 4, and I want to use it in my WP7 project.

I referenced the dll in the WP7 project and couldn't use the control I've created. I need to know what statement I should add into my xaml file before using the control.

this is the xaml file of the class library (only a rectangle):

```
<UserControl x:Class="NabbeshControls.ProfileBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFABABFF" Margin="10" Stroke="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the namespace for the control in your library is "NabbeshControls" and the dll is called "Nabbesh.dll", add the following to the top of the XAML in which u want to use it:

```
 xmlns:tryNabbesh="clr-namespace:NabbeshControls;assembly=Nabbesh"
```